# Re-used UITableViewCell showing old UIImageView for a moment then switches to correct image

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

So I've built a custom cell for a UITableView.  My subclassed UITableViewCell has a UIImageView in it.  When scrolling through the table view, as the new cells appear, the "left-over" images from the dequeued cells are shown for a moment until the new image loads in it's place.

I've tried [cell.myImage setImage:nil] but that doesn't seem to have any effect.  How can I prevent this problem?

Note that I'm loading the images in another thread (they're coming off the web).

Comment: I ended up just changing the cellidentifier to reflect each cell instead of a generic cell for every row...stupid mistake on my park.  unfortunately the scrolling is still slow because i'm using a nib instead of drawing everything myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also set it to nil

Answer (score 1):

I was able to setImage with a blank png.  This prevent the old image from being displayed.